# Is there a way to put a total row beneath my dataGridView in PrintDocument?

Tags: c#, printing, datagridview

I'm trying to build an invoice like PrintDocument, is there any way I can get the sum of my "Totaal" rows, which is in a textbox named "Totaalregel", beneath my printed dataGridView?

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Set the left margin
        int iLeftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
        //Set the top margin
        int iTopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
        //Whether more pages have to print or not
        bool bMorePagesToPrint = false;
        int iTmpWidth = 0;

        //For the first page to print set the cell width and header height
        if (bFirstPage)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in dataGridView2.Columns)
            {
                iTmpWidth = (int)(Math.Floor((double)((double)GridCol.Width /
                               (double)iTotalWidth * (double)iTotalWidth *
                               ((double)e.MarginBounds.Width / (double)iTotalWidth))));

                iHeaderHeight = (int)(e.Graphics.MeasureString(GridCol.HeaderText,
                            GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font, iTmpWidth).Height) + 11;

                // Save width and height of headres
                arrColumnLefts.Add(iLeftMargin);
                arrColumnWidths.Add(iTmpWidth);
                iLeftMargin += iTmpWidth;
            }
        }

        //Loop till all the grid rows not get printed
        while (iRow <= dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1)
        {
            DataGridViewRow GridRow = dataGridView2.Rows[iRow];
            //Set the cell height
            iCellHeight = GridRow.Height + 5;
            int iCount = 0;
            //Check whether the current page settings allo more rows to print
            if (iTopMargin + iCellHeight >= e.MarginBounds.Height + e.MarginBounds.Top)
            {
                bNewPage = true;
                bFirstPage = false;
                bMorePagesToPrint = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (bNewPage)
                {
                    //Draw Header
                    e.Graphics.DrawString("Factuur", new Font(dataGridView2.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                            Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top -
                            e.Graphics.MeasureString("Factuur", new Font(dataGridView2.Font,
                            FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13);

                    String strDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " +
                                     DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

                    //Draw Date
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(strDate, new Font(dataGridView2.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                            Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width -
                            e.Graphics.MeasureString(strDate, new Font(dataGridView1.Font,
                            FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Width), e.MarginBounds.Top -
                            e.Graphics.MeasureString("Factuur", new Font(new
                                Font(dataGridView2.Font,
                                FontStyle.Bold), 
                            FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13);

                    //Draw Columns                 
                    iTopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
                    foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in dataGridView2.Columns)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.LightGray),
                            new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                            (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black,
                            new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                            (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

                        e.Graphics.DrawString(GridCol.HeaderText, GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font,
                            new SolidBrush(GridCol.InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                            new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                            (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight), strFormat);
                        iCount++;
                    }
                    bNewPage = false;
                    iTopMargin += iHeaderHeight;
                }
                iCount = 0;
                //Draw Columns Contents                
                foreach (DataGridViewCell Cel in GridRow.Cells)
                {
                    if (Cel.Value != null)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(Cel.Value.ToString(), Cel.InheritedStyle.Font,
                                    new SolidBrush(Cel.InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                                    new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], (float)iTopMargin,
                                    (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], (float)iCellHeight), strFormat);
                    }

                    //Drawing Cells Borders 
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount],
                            iTopMargin, (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iCellHeight));

                    iCount++;
                }
            }

            iRow++;
            iTopMargin += iCellHeight;
        }

        //If more lines exist, print another page.
        if (bMorePagesToPrint)
            e.HasMorePages = true;
        else
            e.HasMorePages = false;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Here is the idea I am looking for:

[image: example]

Comment: Well, of course, it is just another Graphics.DrawString() call.  That it is hard to figure out where to put it is because you wrote a God method.  Split it up.

Answer (score 0):

You could just put your Total Rows as a Datagridview item at the bottom if your code is producing the whole datagridview onto your print then it should retrieve the total row as well.

Or you could place it at the end of your code so once e.HasManyPages has been declared false just before that you can have your segment of print code with e.Graphics to produce the string you want. If the total is just the string from the text box then you will be invoking that string onto your print.